# UpperCase Replace(Split_Part())

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Community,
I need assistance with removing the UNDER SCORES '_' and make the name readable first name letter UpperCase last name UpperCase, while removing the number as well. Hope this makes sense. I am running Presto and using Query Fabric. I there a better way to write this syntax?

Email Address

Full_Metal_Jacket@movie.com

TOP_GUN2@movie.email.com

Needed Outcome

Full Metal Jacket

Top Gun

Partical working Resolution:

```
,REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(T.EMAIL, '@', 1),'_',' ') Name
```

Something like this:

```
 ,LOWER(REPLACE(UPPER(SPLIT_PART(T.EMAIL, '@', 1)),'_',' '))Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
WITH t(email) AS (
    VALUES 'Full_Metal_Jacket@movie.com', 'TOP_GUN2@movie.email.com'
)
SELECT array_join(
    transform(
        split(regexp_extract(email, '(^[^0-9@]+)', 1), '_'),
        part -> upper(substr(part, 1, 1)) || lower(substr(part, 2))),
    ' ')
FROM t;
```

How it works:

- extract the non-numeric prefix up to the @ using a regex via [`regexp_extract`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html?highlight=regexp_extract#regexp_extract)
- [`split`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/string.html?highlight=split#split) the prefix on _ to produce an array
- [`transform`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html?highlight=transform#transform) the array by capitalizing the first letter of each element and lowercasing the rest.
- Finally, join them all together with a space using the [`array_join`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html?highlight=array_join#array_join) function.

**Update**:

Here's another variant without involving `transform` and the intermediate array:

```
regexp_replace(
    replace(regexp_extract(email, '(^[^0-9@]+)', 1), '_', ' '),
    '(\w)(\w*)',
    x -> upper(x[1]) || lower(x[2]))
```

Like the approach above, it first extracts the non-numeric prefix, then it replaces underscores with spaces with the `replace` function, and finally, it uses [`regexp_replace`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html?highlight=regexp_replace#regexp_replace) to process each word. The `(\w)(\w*)` regular expression captures the first letter of the word and the rest of the word into two separate capture groups. The `x -> upper(x[1]) || lower(x[2])` lambda expression then capitalizes the first letter (first capture group -- `x[1]`) and lower cases the rest (second capture group -- `x[2]`).

Comment: @ martin - That worked perfectly, thank you. Thanks for the explaination.